# Apache rewrite rules not working

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

A basic rewrite rule is not working and I have no idea why. Here's my *hanalulu.conf*:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName hanalulu.localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/hanalulu/public
DirectoryIndex index.php

<Directory />
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^a.html$ b.html

</VirtualHost>
```

After I have added an extra line in `hosts` file and enabled the site via `sudo a2ensite`. Restarted web server: `hanalulu.localhost/a.html` requests `a.html` instead of `b.html`.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think you need the slashes in your path and the flags on the RewriteRule, try this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName hanalulu.localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/hanalulu/public
DirectoryIndex index.php

<Directory />
    AllowOverride all
    Order Deny,Allow
    Deny from all
    Allow from 127.0.0.1
</Directory>

RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^/a.html$ /b.html [R,L]

</VirtualHost>
```